# Return type of method which fill comboBox

Tags: java, combobox

I'm working on a simple GUI where I drag combobox and edit the values here I i have a class categories and then 3 methods of rice,sweets and meal. I would like to be to call these three methods on my frame and then from there I want to fill the values into the combo box. An important thing that these 3 methods of categories `class` are connected with access so they fetch data from there. My question is: What will be the return type of these particular methods?

```
public String rice()
    {


        String query ="select * from categories";

        String end=null;
        String a ;
        try{
            ps=conn.prepareStatement(query);
            rs=ps.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next())
            {
                end=end+rs.getString("Rice")+"\t";

            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return end;
    }`
```

now in another class

`Combo_boxes obj = new Combo_boxes();
  comboBox.addItem(obj.rice());`

When I call this method  it will to return a value of 1 row of database and then I want to place it into the combo box and then next row so from this,i will place every item from database. When I update my database it should automatically update the combo box.

Comment: Please try to improve your English by adding punctuation, using a spelling checker, and if possible correcting the grammar.

Comment: Graham asher thanks i make it more clear as i can i"ll be very thankful to you if you answer my question